# PC Shut Down & Blue Screening?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, shutdown, desktop-computer

I have recently upgraded my motherboard in my computer before that I had a standard small board but now I have a big gaming one (forgot the exact size names think its atx or something)

Anyway,
Sometimes after a while of using the system the hard drive makes a sound like when the reader goes back in place (the sound when you shut the down the system) 
after that sound the pc will freeze it also does it sometimes when installing updates which is bad.

I already had to re-install windows 3 times since when the disk is doing something it is corrupting data.

I have a few times had vertices lines go across the screen then I had to restart the system this happened this morning but after that windows loaded with no graphics driver then a few seconds after windows logged in it then went to a blue screen which is odd on it self.

The most common issue is the hard drive sounding like it is losing power and the it freezing also sometimes it will make that sound and the pc won't freeze so I think it may be the PSU as it is 500W or the psu could be on it's way out.

It is a fairly new system but the psu is 6 months old.

What do you all think and what can I do to prevent this from happening because I fix the issue till i get paid next which is in a few weeks.

the system is fine for now as I am writing this post on the PC it just randomly happens when it fells like it lol..

PS: I have tried my gaming card and I got the vertical lines a few days ago and also on the on board graphics. to me sounds like components are losing power need your thoughts on this as will

Comment: Please provide exact details.  You not being able to provide exact information is not acceptable.  When I had this problem it was caused by a display driver.  Additionally download BlueScreenViewer and provide information on what drivers were loaded at the time of the crash.

Comment: it is hard to explain all it fells like is that the computer is losing power to the component's.
and the disk might not be spining fast enough as it takes a long time to do windows updates and sometimes crashes but makes the reset sound like power was taking from it.

I have re-installed windows multiply times

Comment: maybe upgrading the psu will fix the problem?

Comment: You have not told us anything about the system.  How can we answer a question like that?